# Provisioning profile doesn't include signing certificate

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

I am using XCode version 15.2 and I am trying to build an IPA file for testing among our testing devices. Since I don't have a device attached to the developer account (one that is attached needs to wait 30 days for it to be valid), I am choosing manual signing. I am facing the problem of "Provisioning profile doesn't include signing certificate" problem which many others seem to be facing. None of the solutions suggested on online forums seem to work. I would like to know the steps which work.